# Regular Expression not working in iOS with $ character

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am new to RegularExpressions in iOS . I am using Regular Expression in some part of my code but its not working . Correct me if I am doing Something wrong

I am calling the compareStringWithRegex function like this

```
[self compareStringWithRegex:@"Web" withRegexPattern@"eb$"];
```

Method

```
- (BOOL)compareStringWithRegex:(NSString *)string
              withRegexPattern:(NSString *)expression {
  @try {

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
        regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                             options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                               error:&error];

    NSTextCheckingResult *match =
        [regex firstMatchInString:string
                          options:0
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length] - 1)];

    if (match) {
      return YES;
    } else {
      return NO;
    }
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception) {

    // NSLog(@"the exception in checking regex is %@",[exception description]);
  }
}
```

But its not matching

Comment: You checked its called and that there is no error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified code little bit. I think this will help you and hope this is what you needed

```
- (BOOL)compareStringWithRegex:(NSString *)string
          withRegexPattern:(NSString *)expression {
@try {

    NSError *error = NULL;

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:expression
                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                  error:&error];

    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                    options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (match) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

    // NSLog(@"the exception in checking regex is %@",[exception description]);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @user3115014 , Please give the parameter in this way.     [self compareStringWithRegex:@"Web" withRegexPattern:@"eb*"]; It works here..

Comment: but the end of string regular expression is with $ right ? with * it works .

Comment: @user3115014 Yep, $ is end of the string. It will also work for pattern "eb$". Please check, it works for me.If it didn't work for you, please let me know i can help you further.